# Best way to parse HTML these days?

Tags: c#, html, xml, parsing, xslt

So I have a program I wrote that parses some HTML. The interesting thing about this is that it is written in a way that it can parse different pages (with similar data) using the same codebase and not rewriting the parsing code. Its a parsing engine of sorts if you will.

The way my current version works is that it converts HTML to XHTML and then I use XSLT (currently 1.0 in C#) transforms to transform the data into a normalized data structure that my app can easily consume and serialize. This allows me to simply write a new XSLT transform for each page I want to parse the data out of and it will simply work without rewriting code or writing any new parsing code.

I am curious if this is still currently my best option or is there something else out there that is better. I currently have a dilemma because XSLT 2.0 is actually not terribly easy to find support for without paying tons of cash and XSLT in general is a bit meh to deal with. I am curious if there is something more viable and simpler to use for the same purpose.

The solutions I am looking for must be usable in C++ and/or C# (.net). The simpler and lightweight the better.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack. /thread.

Comment: [linky](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for the above comment

Answer (score 3):

Just  use code with  htmlAgilityPack and you can manipulate the html page as an  xmlDoc. Following a code sample on  how you can achieve this

```
        HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();          
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlTextWriter xmlTxtWriter = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.ASCII);            
        htmlWeb.LoadHtmlAsXml(uriofhtmlPageToload, xmlTxtWriter);
        ms.Position = 0;
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(ms);
        XElement xHtml = xdoc.Root;
        string nameSpace = "{" + xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().ToString() + "}";
        XElement xBody = xHtml.Element(nameSpace + "body");
        List<XElement> xBodyElts = xBody.Descendants().ToList();
        string elt = string.Empty;
        foreach (var eltPage in xBodyElts)
        {
           //here just to show that you can iterate as xmlDoc 
          }
```

Comment: This looks really nice actually although I don't feel it completely answers my question. This is essentially the same solution I already have and have been using. Just now there is one library for converting to XML. It still seems to rely on C# internals and only supports XSLT 1.0. This also still leaves me with writing XSLT transforms or writing custom parsing code using LINQ or straight up C# for each page I want to parse.

The main advantage of using XSLT is that the script or transform simply can be downloaded meaning no new build just to support a new page.